# PHP - Non WSDL local xsd schema

Tags: php, soap, xsd, soap-client

How to include local XSD schemas in a non-WSDL PHP `SoapClient`?

The server gives this error when I try to call a method `Could not find schema information for the element 'http://localserver/schema.php?:schemaname'`

Server is a Windows server using ASP.

Comment: To clarify, the WSDL and XSD are both local. Is that correct?